# Can I use .htaccess for redirects?

Tags: .htaccess

I am using coppermine gallery, the only suggestion so far, on their help forum, was to inquire with stackoverflow. Problem - when you click on one of the Categories on main page It goes to "No image to Display". I would like it to go to something like "You must be logged in to view these pages" or something like that. The coppermine forum suggested maybe redirects in an .htaccess file? Is that the best way? I think the easiest way to explain is this: When you Click on Coudy here:http://stalag13000.net/Gallery/index.php it goes to "No image to display" but I would like it to at least go to here:http://stalag13000.net/Gallery/login.php?referer=index.php%3Fcat%3D2

I did see some posts on .htaccess but I am far from knowing if any of that could or would apply to my scenario,

Thanks for any help or direction,

yamiacaveman

Comment: You should consider showing us your trials.

Comment: A redirect would be really bad UX. Why not just display "You must be logged in to view this!", and then a login form where the image would be?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to display info only to people who are logged in, you would check in the

```
$_ SESSION
```

variable to see if they are logged in or not. If they are not, you would then direct them with php to the login page.

```
header('Location: /login.php');
```

[header location with php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

I like Ollie Ford's suggestion. You could open a modal over the current screen, ask for them to login there and then, on success, you could thank them, close the modal, and show the content on the page.

Comment: Thanks tlindell for your answer - the session thing, yeah.

Comment: Hi Ollie and Benoit Thanks for your response - I wish I knew how to display "You must be logged in --" Would have solved my problem. Trials, lol, when your dumb like a tree stump. I can see this forum is way above the limbs of this tree stump. Thanks everyone, someday?

Comment: I am curious if we have answered your question successfully yet or not. If we have not, where can we help? If so, you can mark this answer as the best one if it helped you. Let me know either way.